# jquery parse json issue

Tags: jquery, ajax

I have got one app running on two servers, one works and one doesnt cant understand why.

ajax query..

```
 $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "WebService.asmx/GetFinish1",
        data: '{' +
                        'Item:"' + item + '"' +
                   '}',
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (msg) {
            var data = jQuery.parseJSON(msg);
            $("#item").val(JSON.stringify(msg));
```

at line `$("#item").val(JSON.stringify(msg));` from one i get...

```
{"d":"{\"0\":{\"i\":\"MODIFIED C/W TOOL MC WALL\",\"D\":\"Notes\",\"V\":\"MODIFIED C/W TOOL MC WALL\"},\"1\":{\"i\":\"EA\",\"D\":\"Unit\",\"V\":\"EA\"},\"2\":{\"i\":\"EA\",\"D\":\"Unit\",\"De\":\"Unit\",\"V\":\"EA\"}}"}
```

the second i get

```
"{\"0\":{\"i\":\"1x 8351-3  &  2 x 8352-3\",\"D\":\"Notes\",\"V\":\"1x 8351-3  &  2 x 8352-3\"},\"1\":{\"i\":\"PC3\",\"D\":\"Unit\",\"V\":\"PC3\"},\"2\":{\"i\":\"PC3\",\"D\":\"Unit\",\"De\":\"Unit\",\"V\":\"PC3\"}}"
```

the second one works, the first doesnt, but why the difference? same code! where does the extra {} and d: come from?

Comment: Are you positive both servers are running the same code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need

```
var data = jQuery.parseJSON(msg);
$("#item").val(JSON.stringify(msg));
```

Because, `msg` is already JSON formatted due to `dataType: 'json'` used in `ajax` property.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why, but I had to use the following `var data = jQuery.parseJSON(msg.d);`